# Invalid data source used for data list

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Any suggestions as to where this error could stem from?

```
 "An invalid data source is being used for DataList1. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable."
```

This piece of code is highlighted for the error:

```
DataList1.DataSource = FilmsAccess.GetFilmDetails(filmId);
```

The GetFilmDetails method calls a Stored Procedure and returns a table with ALL the fields that I specify in the .aspx datalist (which is "data bind"-ed to this method). Thanks in advance. 
Anna

EDIT: Please check my own answer to this. I clarified the solution there, as well as raised another related question!

Comment: Please show your code for GetFilmDetails

Comment: It seems your `GetFilmDetails` is not returning a valid `IEnumerable`

Comment: The error is very clear, if you read the message. `A valid list source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.` This means that whatever `GetFilmDetails()` returns must not implement either of them.

Comment: If it returns a DataTable try FilmsAccess.GetFilmDetails(filmId).Rows

Comment: I still don't know what an IEnumerable/IListSource is really.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! "TheGeekYouNeed", you just made me realise something utterly important! The GetFilmDetails method does not in fact return a table, but a structure. I made it return a table, so now it works! - I love it how through these suggestions, I am being taught which details to pay attention to, whereas initially I don't know where to start debugging. Very helpful!

Now, I have one more related question:
Can someone help understand why if the datatype returned is a structure as opposed to a table, this error is thrown? I specify that:

1. The structure has field1, field2, field3, etc...
2. The table has the exact same information in column1, column2,
   etc.
3. The fields and the column names are called exactly the same. The
   reference in aspx to them is like: Eval("field1").ToString().

Comment: `IEnumerable`\`IListSource` are what are used to be able to iterate using `foreach` instead of requiring an integer index. Your structure doesn't have one of these interfaces defined for it, and therefore can't be iterated as it needs to be. (Your 'related question' should really have been a separate question, though.)

Comment: Thanks Ken! So is there a way to 'trick' the system in this case into accepting a structure, or is a table the only option when using `Eval("fieldname")` ? I mean, **how does the system know that an IListSource is needed?** Just because of the `Eval("x")` ? Trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: No, Anna. It's because one of those two interfaces is **required** of anything that is to be used as a `DataSource`. It's the way things use the `DataSource` to retrieve the individual rows - through whichever of those two interfaces it supports, but it **knows** that it can use one of those two interfaces because they're **required**. If they're not there, the data type doesn't meet the requirements and can't be used as a datasource. Consider that your car **requires** gasoline to work, and if you don't supply it it won't work. You can't just put any fluid into the tank; it has to be gas.

Comment: Thank you. To put it in another way for my understanding - I might use somewhere in the the project: `x.rows[0]`, so for that to work, x needs to be a table, because a structure doesn't have rows, whereas a table, does have that property. Only problem is, I don't use x.rows[0] and I can't **fingerpoint** a single situation in the code that makes it **obvious** that the data source must be a table. But hopefully I got the point. And I understand we can use structures with Eval("x") as well, that's not the **indicator** I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: No. Assigning it to the DataSource will allow the **datasource** internally to access the interfaces. It has nothing to do with you manually accessing `x.Row[]`. You can use any structure or object you like, as long as it exposes one of the two interfaces. Read my example again about gasoline above - you don't have to know anything about the internal workings of the internal combustion engine to understand you have to supply gas to make it work. You don't have to specifically push the gas through the fuel injector nozzle or understand the four strokes the piston makes to drive it.